# Added Meta tag UTF 8 but the character encoding of the HTML document was not declared still getting it

Tags: php, html, character-encoding

I am getting error in console even I added UTF-8

> The character encoding of the HTML document was not declared. The document will render with garbled text in some browser configurations if the document contains characters from outside the US-ASCII range. The character encoding of the page must be declared in the document or in the transfer protocol.

I already added in HMTL head.

```
<meta content="text/html;charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type">
<meta content="utf-8" http-equiv="encoding">
```

If I delete below my PHP code from HTML then It's working properly

Note: `$GET['Key']` values comes from `URL(domain.com/details?key=uYxnJrS3aLv0JbJFLnnmW4TRRpF6%2FYB0JD6LUhPYu0U%3D)`

```
if ($conn->real_escape_string($_GET['key'])){
     $p_id=$conn->real_escape_string($_GET['key']);
     $decrypted_p_id = decryptIt($p_id);
     /*display single products*/
     $sql_single_products="SELECT p_images, p_name, p_company, p_status FROM products WHERE p_id=?";
     if ($stmt = $conn->prepare($sql_single_products)) {
          $stmt->bind_param("i", $decrypted_p_id);
          $stmt->execute();
          $stmt->bind_result($p_images, $name,$company,$status);
          $stmt->fetch();
     }
}
```

Below Is the function to change my ID encryption to decryption and vice and versa

```
function encryptIt( $q ) {
    $cryptKey  = 'qJB0rGtIn5UB1xG03efyCp';
    $qEncoded      = base64_encode( mcrypt_encrypt( MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256, md5( $cryptKey ), $q, MCRYPT_MODE_CBC, md5( md5( $cryptKey ) ) ) );
    return( $qEncoded );
}

function decryptIt( $q ) {
    $cryptKey  = 'qJB0rGtIn5UB1xG03efyCp';
    $qDecoded      = rtrim( mcrypt_decrypt( MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256, md5( $cryptKey ), base64_decode( $q ), MCRYPT_MODE_CBC, md5( md5( $cryptKey ) ) ), "\0");
    return( $qDecoded );
}
```

**Connection.php**

```
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "user";
$password = "Pass#@123";
$dbname = "dbname";
// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
$conn->set_charset('utf8');
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}
```

After adding `$conn->set_charset('utf8');` in database connection file getting
 and also added `ini_set('display_errors', 1);` then I am getting error

```
Allowed memory size of 268435456 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 4294967296 bytes)
```

Comment: is your database used utf8 for charset?

Comment: I don't know. Where should I set it?

Comment: phpmyadmin, and look your database list. in there have a information about charset

Comment: I am able to access this on localhost but not able to access on the server.

Comment: If I delete my PHP code then it's working.

Comment: does `MySQL` generate any errors?

Comment: @SalimIbrogimov, No I am not getting any error but after adding $conn->set_charset('utf8') then I am getting Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 4294967296 bytes)

Comment: So you have an encoding issue or a memory issue? Don't escape and parameterize.

Comment: @chris85, Actually I added  $conn->set_charset('utf8') in my database connection page as per Salim lbrogimov said to me then I got memory issue.

Comment: Is the code in a loop or anything? The block being executed is `if ($conn->real_escape_string($_GET['key'])){`?

Comment: And I remove $conn->set_charset('utf8')  from database file and I am getting blank page and If I delete PHP Code(Prepared statement) then I am getting my HTML CODE

Comment: @chris85, NO code is not in the loop. I am retrieving single information with the help of Id, I am able to use in local system but not able to use it on server

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I found my answer.
What I did, I created a php.ini file in the public_html folder and added below code in it.

```
memory_limit = 512M // before it was 256M if you want to check the current limit then add  `php_info();` in your PHP file then run your file.and find memory_limit.
post_max_size = 32M;
upload_max_filesize = 32M;
```

but still, I was getting the issue. I was using prepared statement then I added

```
$stmt->store_result();
```

before `$stmt->bind_result()` and this time it was working perfeclty.

If anyone getting the same issue then try this solution.

Answer (score 0):

You should write:

```
<meta charset="utf-8" />
```

Comment: You need to check DataBase charset; when You create connection with DB You set default charset like: `$conn->set_charset('utf8')`

Comment: After adding above charset in DB I am getting some different error.  Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 4294967296 bytes)

Comment: And getting error on line no is $stmt->bind_result($p_images, $name,$company,$status); in my PHP code.